# Delete a record from a specific table when a submission is deleted

Tags: 8, webforms

Is it possible to delete a record from a specific table when a webform submission is deleted?

I know it's possible in Drupal 7, with `hook_webform_submission_delete()`.
The code I would use in Drupal 7 is similar to the following one.

```php
function app_webform_submission_delete($node, $submission) {
  $id = $submission->data[7][0];
  // Delete a record from x table when a submission is deleted.
  db_delete('x_table')
    ->condition('type', "submission_type")
    ->condition('nid', $id)
    ->condition('sid', $submission->sid)
    ->execute();
}
```

What would the code for Drupal 8 be?

My question, in fact, is: How to respond to a specific webform submission deletion in drupal 8? In my code when a webform is submitted i insert sid with information in a custom table. When a specific submission is deleted i want to delete as well the record inserted in the custom table that have the deleted submission sid.

Comment: Can somebody help me please? I do not know how to do it in drupal 8. Maybe it is a stupid question but i do not know how to do this. Thank you

Comment: How were you able to add it to `x_table`?

Comment: No Sssweat, in witch environment do you ask (D8 or D7)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be very careful when executing direct delete queries on a table. I am not sure if your `x_table` is a "Drupal" table or a custom table that you had created. Preferably you should use the Drupal API to ensure records for entities or such are deleted gracefully.

If the record that you are trying to delete is an entity ie. a node, then you would do something like:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
$node->delete();
```

Alternatively use the `database` service for non-entities:

```
\Drupal::database()->delete('x_table')
  ->condition('foo', 'bar')
  ->execute();
```

You can put this code in your implementation of hook `hook_webform_submission_delete()`.

Comment: x_table is a custom table. hook_webform_submission_delete() it is still available for D8?

Comment: Look in webform.api.php @Yan187, the info is all in there

Comment: @Clive i did not fount anything related with hook_webform_submission_delete() in webform.api.php

Comment: I solved. Thanx to @Clive and baikho